# -U and -bitcode_bundle (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE=YES) cannot be used together in Xcode 13

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I'm facing this issue when I try to run the app in Xcode. my Xcode version is 13.2.1 (13C100)

-U and -bitcode_bundle (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE=YES) cannot be used together

Here's my podfile

```
$RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '13.0'
install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false

target 'Mcsc' do
  use_frameworks!
  config = use_native_modules!

  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'

  pod 'GoogleMaps'

  pod 'RNFBApp', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app'
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCoreInternal', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseStorage', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseStorageInternal', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseAppCheckInterop', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseAuthInterop', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCoreExtension', :modular_headers => true

  permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'
  pod 'Permission-LocationWhenInUse', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationWhenInUse"

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'McscTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.
  # use_flipper!()

  pre_install do |installer|
    Pod::Installer::Xcode::TargetValidator.send(:define_method, :verify_no_static_framework_transitive_dependencies) {}
    installer.pod_targets.each do |pod|
      if pod.name.eql?('RNPermissions') || pod.name.start_with?('Permission-')
        def pod.build_type;
          # Uncomment the line corresponding to your CocoaPods version
          Pod::BuildType.static_library # >= 1.9
          # Pod::Target::BuildType.static_library # < 1.9
        end
      end
    end
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    # config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
    # Pod::Installer::Xcode::TargetValidator.send(:define_method, :verify_no_static_framework_transitive_dependencies) {}
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
    `sed -i -e  $'s/__IPHONE_10_0/__IPHONE_12_0/' Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/portability/Time.h`
  end
end
```

Any help would be great! I tried disabling bitcode and it still showed ENABLE_BITCODE=YES in the error message - cleaned my build folder too. Really out of ideas right now.

Comment: Getting same error don't know what to do -_-

Answer (score 3):

Bitcode is deprecated in Xcode 14. So, it is perhaps best to simply disable it, then there's no problem. In Podfile in postinstall add these lines

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
      end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to remove `use_frameworks!` and use

```
  pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
  $RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true
```

instead.
So my Podfile looked like this

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '12.4'
install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false


target 'opinion' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
  $RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # Hermes is now enabled by default. Disable by setting this flag to false.
    # Upcoming versions of React Native may rely on get_default_flags(), but
    # we make it explicit here to aid in the React Native upgrade process.
    :hermes_enabled => true,
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # Enables Flipper.
    #
    # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
    # you should disable the next line.
    :flipper_configuration => FlipperConfiguration.enabled,
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'opinionTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      # Set `mac_catalyst_enabled` to `true` in order to apply patches
      # necessary for Mac Catalyst builds
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end
```